# Как понять, откуда вызван метод asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, запрос

На сайте asp.net один и тот-же метод контроллера вызывается из разных мест (например кнопка обратной связи на главной странице и кнопка на странице контактов). Как понять, откуда именно вызывается запрос, чтобы записать это как свойство обьекта обратной связи в БД?

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался. При каждом клике по ссылке вызывается функция и передаю ей конкретный аргумент в виде `ID`. Соответственно, в каждом месте, где она вызывается - свой `ID`.

По такому принципу можно различить место из которого вызвана функция. Вопрос решен.